# Modern C++ way of doing function return pointer to a function

Tags: c++, pointers

I am new to C++ and I started to reading a book on the topic. There is an exercise that says: "Declare a pointer to a function taking an int as argument and returning a pointer to a function that takes a char as argument and returns float". I ended up with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float func(char c) {
    return 3.14;
}

float((*fun2(int))(char)) {
    return &func;
}

int main() {
    float(*fp)(char) = fun2(3);
    cout << fp('c') << endl;
}
```

The question is: is it still appropriate in today's C++ programming. If so - are there any needed changes to be made to the code(applying new abstractions etc.)? Thanks.

Comment: Usually people use a `typedef` to make the syntax less insane.

Comment: BTW, `float(*fp)(char) = fun2;` is not correct. You need to make the function call, such as `float(*fp)(char) = fun2(10);`

Comment: As I read the question ("Declare a pointer..."), the answer should be a single variable declaration.

Comment: If you're interested in modern C++ then do make an effort to kick that `using namespace std` habit. That namespace separation serves a purpose.

Comment: @R Sahu: it was typo from my side ... Thanks.

Comment: _The question is: is it still appropriate in today's C++ programming_ one may argue that it wasn’t appropriate in yesterday’s C++. std::sort doesn’t rely on function pointers as in contrast qsort does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare a type alias:

```
using my_fp = float ( * )(char); // can work before C++11 with typedef

my_fp fun2(int){
  return &func;
}

my_fp fp = fun2(0);
```

and / or completely automatic type deduction:

```
auto fun2(int) { // available in C++14
  return &func;
}

// Use a suitable value in the call to fun2
auto fp{fun2(0)}; // available in C++11
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the problem states to return a "function pointer", you are sort of stuck with slightly old syntax. However, if you aren't constrained by that and just want to return a function (and C interoperability isn't an issue), you can use `std::function`, which is a more modern, more general function type.

```
#include <functional>

// ...

std::function<float(char)> fun2(int) {
  return &func;
}
```

The advantage to `std::function` (aside from looking prettier than the awkward `float(*)(char)` syntax) is that it can store function pointers, anonymous functions, and callable objects, whereas a traditional function pointer can *only* store pointers to global functions. So, for example, the following would be allowed.

```
struct Foo {
  float operator()(char) {
    // ...
  }
};

std::function<float(char)> fun3(int) {
  return Foo();
}

std::function<float(char)> fun4(int) {
  return [](char) { return 1.0; };
}
```

Neither of `fun3` nor `fun4` would compile with a simple function pointer.

Comment: You should also mention disadvantages of `std::function`: allocation overhead, invocation overhead, lack of compatibility with regular function pointers which may be still an issue when dealing with C interop.

Answer (score 2):

As alternative, there is the trailing return type (since C++11):

```
auto fun2(int) -> float(*)(char)
{
    return &func;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My literal version:

```
#include <iostream>

using my_pf = float(*)(char);
using my_ppf = my_pf(*)(int);

float func(char)
{
    return 3.14f;
}

my_pf fun2(int)
{
    return &func;
}


int main()
{

    my_ppf ppf; // Your declaration: 
                // Pointer to a function taking an int as argument
                // and returning a pointer to a function
                // that takes a char as argument and returns float.

    ppf = &fun2; 

    my_pf pf = ppf(3);

    std::cout << pf('c') << '\n';

}
```