# f is a pointer to function that takes int and returns pointer to function that takes nothing and returns double

Tags: c++, function, pointers, return

So I guess I have to make the third function that returns a pointer to function, and I will be able to choose between `fun` and `fun2`.

```
double fun()
{
    double x = 10.1;
    return x;
}

double fun2()
{
    double x = 19.9;
    return x;
}


int main() {
    double (*(*f)(int))();     
}
```

How to complete this code and practically use it? Can anyone finish it?

Comment: How to complete this code and practically use it? Can anyone finish it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. What did you try to solve this issue 
and what problem did you encounter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modern C++ way of doing function return pointer to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268283/modern-c-way-of-doing-function-return-pointer-to-a-function)

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48270005/4386427 seems to do nearly what you ask for

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to pass a parameter (here to `getFunction`) to decide which pointer is returned:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

double fun()
{
    double x = 10.1;
    return x;
}

double fun2()
{
    double x = 19.9;
    return x;
}

double (*getFunction(int n))() {
    return n == 1 ? &fun : &fun2;
}

int main() {
    double (*f1)() = getFunction(1);
    double (*f2)() = getFunction(2);
    printf("Result 1: %f\n", f1());
    printf("Result 2: %f\n", f2());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggest `#include <iostream>` and, e.g. `std::cout << "Result 1: " <<  f1() << '\n';`

Comment: You're right. I was working on C. Thanks.